# Using shell script parameters with colons in awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a file which contains rows having this format:

```
2011/09/14 12:00:23.525 text
```

I wrote a shell script which searches for a given expression in *text* and sorts all the matching rows by day and time. At the end, I would like to discard the entries referring to an instant which is older than that passed as parameter. I use awk to make this kind of filtering. The script looks like this:

```
search=$1  file=$2  day=$3  time=$4
zgrep -h "$search" $file | sort -k1,1 -k2,2 | awk -v da="$day" ti="$time" '($1 >= day) && ($2>= ti) {print $0}' > out.$$
```

If I invoke:

```
myScript searchThis file1.txt 2011/09/20 09:16:52.130
```

I get this error:

```
awk: ti=09:16:52.130
awk:      ^ syntax error
```

Can you please help me to solve this?
Thanks a lot! 
Bye

Comment: Don't you need `-v` before both variation assignments?

Comment: ｀($1 >= day) && ($2>= ti)｀ is not correct. what happens if Date part > day but time part < given ti? e.g. 2050/01/01 01:01:01 and 1999/01/01 22:22:22.

Comment: @KAK, thank you very much, I forgot the -v which was part of the problem.

Comment: @Kent, thank you too.. I really didn't think about.. This should work: '($1 > da) || ($1==da && ($2>= ti)) {print $0}, right? Thanks again!

Comment: It might be as easy to use string concatenation: `($1 $2) >= (da ti) {print}`

Answer (score 2):

can you wrap the para value in `"`?
I tested this under bash and zsh, both worked:

```
kent$  cat a
2011/09/20 09:16:52.130 
2011/08/20 10:16:52.130 
2011/07/20 05:16:52.130

kent$  d="2011/08/30 00:23:23"   #here used ".." to wrap the date and time

kent$  awk -v d="$d" '$0>d' a
2011/09/20 09:16:52.130
```

don't know if it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Kent's answer didn't work for me. I'm using GNU Awk 4.1.3 in cygwin.

I eventually found this [awk: passing variables from bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771543/awk-passing-variables-from-bash) where dubiousjim mentioned that you can specify the variable value after the action. It won't be available in the BEGIN rule but that was fine for my case.

So you can change your script to something like:

```
search=$1  file=$2  day=$3  time=$4
zgrep -h "$search" $file | sort -k1,1 -k2,2 | awk '($1 >= day) && ($2>= ti) {print $0}' da="$day" ti="$time" > out.$$
```